# How exactly does does friction rotate a wheel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, free-body-diagram

All I know is that the wheel pushes the ground and the ground pushes back (friction). Pls can anyone elaborate on this process?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a vertical force $F$ acts on the wheel (e.g. the weight of a car or truck). The ground now provides a reaction force, known as the Normal force $F_N$:

[image: Principle of fraction]

Now if there acts on the wheel a traction force $F_T$ then in the simple case of static friction, a friction force $F_f$ arises, according to:

$$F_f=\mu F_N$$

where $\mu$ is the static friction coefficient between wheel and ground.

This causes a torque $\tau$ to arise about the wheel's centre of gravity $C$:

$$\tau=F_f R$$

with $R$ the radius of the wheel.

This torque causes angular acceleration $\dot{\omega}$ about $C$:

$$\tau=I\dot{\omega}$$

where $I$ is the inertial moment of the wheel.

So the wheel starts to turn about $C$, counter clockwise in this case.